# How to incorporate an svg loading animation

Tags: javascript

I have two separate html files, one is a menu, and the other is a page loading animated svg. How can I set the page loader to fade out, and the menu page to fade in after it has completed loading?
https://github.com/KravMaguy/menuload

Answer (score 1):

You can merge those 2 files together.

1. Set your menu hidden

   ```
   document.querySelector('#classname').classList.add("hidden");
   ```

   --> classname is the name of your class, if you're using an ID, use .idname.
2. Set a timer for like 10 seconds
3. after timer is on 0 set the svg hidden and set your menu visible

   ```
    document.querySelector('#classname').classList.remove("hidden");
   ```

Comment: When you say merge those files together do you mean I have to change the file structure, or copy and paste components from one file to another? can you please provide more details, I did not understand. Also when you say use a timer are you referring to setTimeout method? I would the loading animation to fadeout whenever the page is ready. hopefully this happens earlier than 10 seconds.